# PVlib install as an editable library to be used in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, fork, pvlib

I am using PyCharm as IDE and would like to use an editable version of PVlib.

I have followed the  instructions in link below and installed PVlib via conda in a virtual environment named pvlib_dev. The pvlib_dev virtual environment requires activation via conda before use and I haven't been able to link this part for PyCharm. Any feedback, suggestions would be appreciated.

https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html

Thank you.
Baran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the conda virtual environment from the PyCharm project settings following these instructions: [Configure a Python interpreter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html). Scroll down to the section on [Setting an existing Python interpreter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#add-existing-interpreter) and enter the path to the python executable in your `pvlib-dev` conda env.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! I have also discovered another method which may or may not be as Pythonic as the suggested solution above from Mark:

1. I have forked the PV-Lib repository in Github
2. Clone this fork into a local folder in my computer
3. In Pycharm, under project settings/ project structure, add the local path of the cloned PV-lib repo under the 'Add Content Root'.
4. Any modifications/ changes I make in the local PV-lib repo is now reflected in my projects as long as I add this local path to 'Add Content Root' and import this PV-lib repo.